# SSRS and duplicated mscorlib references

Tags: .net, reporting-services, mscorlib

Few days ago, after patches applied to the server (Windows Server 2012 SR2, MS SQL 2012 SE [11.0.5388.0]) our SSRS Report Manager stopped to work (Http 500). In log file I found reference to duplicated mscorlib references. Has anyone clue how to fix that issue please?

Log details below:

```
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!532c!01/19/2018-09:52:54:: e ERROR: AppDomain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0 failed to start. Error: (0): error CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
library!DefaultDomain!532c!01/19/2018-09:52:54:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: Failed to create HTTP Runtime, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0.  ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException: (0): error CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectInternal(String appId, Type type, IApplicationHost appHost, Boolean failIfExists, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObject(String appId, Type type, String virtualPath, String physicalPath, Boolean failIfExists, Boolean throwOnError)
   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.RsHttpRuntime.Create(RsAppDomainType type, String vdir, String pdir, Int32& domainId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
appdomainmanager!ReportManager_0-8!532c!01/19/2018-09:52:54:: i INFO: Appdomain:10 ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0-8-131608291715600412 unloading
library!DefaultDomain!532c!01/19/2018-09:52:54:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerAppDomainManagerException: Failed to create Report Server HTTP Runtime, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerAppDomainManagerException: An error occurred when attempting to start the application domain ReportManager within the Report Server service. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0.  ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException: (0): error CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
rshost!rshost!532c!01/19/2018-09:52:54:: e ERROR: Failed to create HttpRuntime 80131500.
rshost!rshost!532c!01/19/2018-09:52:54:: e ERROR: Failed to get appdomain 80131500, pipeline=0x00000006483F3C20.
rshost!rshost!532c!01/19/2018-09:52:54:: e ERROR: Error state. Internal abort for pipeline=0x00000006483F3C20 ...
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!5090!01/19/2018-09:53:09:: i INFO: Appdomain:10 ReportManager_MSSQLSERVER_0-8-131608291715600412 unregistered.
```

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft contribution SSRS issue has been resolved.

The issue was the below mentioned registry key representing the .NET Framework which SSRS was using.

Ideally the ‘OnlyUseLatestCLR’ key should not have been a part of the registry but probably due to installation of some .NET application, this key got applied.

This key forces the .NET run applications to use the .NET 4.0 framework whereas SSRS uses the .NET 3.5 framework and hence it used to fail since it was unable to use the .NET 3.5 framework.

[Windows registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSQfp.jpg)